# How to change style of an unselected element?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I am trying to build a folder viewer with PyQt5 and I encountered a problem.
To mark selected file or directory I made an eventFilter which sets property 'selected' of an QLabel element and applies some styles to it.
The problem is, when I set 'selected' to True - the file/folder is selected (styles applied to it), but when I try set 'selected' to None of previously selected element it is working (the property changes), but styles do not get applied to it (it's not unselects, does not returns to an unselected state).
Here is the fragment of my code:

```
import sys
import os

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QShortcut, QLabel, QPushButton,
                         QGridLayout, QWidget, QMainWindow, QLineEdit,
                         QVBoxLayout, QShortcut, QAction, QMessageBox,
                         QHBoxLayout, QComboBox, QCheckBox, QScrollArea)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIntValidator, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QObject, QEvent, QSize


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(600, 300, 700, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Folder imitator')
        self.homeDirectory = os.path.splitdrive(os.getcwd())[0]+os.path.sep
        self.currentDirectory = self.homeDirectory
        self.setStyleSheet(open('style.css').read())
        self.selected = None
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        cenWidget = QWidget(self)
        mainVertLayout = QVBoxLayout(cenWidget)

        scroll = QScrollArea()
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        viewWidg = QWidget()
        viewVertLayout = QVBoxLayout(viewWidg)
        viewVertLayout.installEventFilter(self)
        viewVertLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        viewVertLayout.setSpacing(0)
        viewVertLayout.setContentsMargins(3, 3, 3, 3)

        self.files = [QLabel(filename) for filename in self.getDirList()]
        for f in self.files:
            f.installEventFilter(self)
            viewVertLayout.addWidget(f)

        scroll.setWidget(viewWidg)

        mainVertLayout.addWidget(scroll)
        mainVertLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        mainVertLayout.setSpacing(0)
        mainVertLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.setCentralWidget(cenWidget)

    def getDirList(self):
        return sorted(os.listdir(self.currentDirectory), 
            key=lambda x : 1 if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(
            self.currentDirectory, x)) and not x.endswith('.BIN') else 2)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            # I am interested in this part
            if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
                if self.selected and self.files[self.selected] != obj:
                    self.files[self.selected].setProperty('selected', None)
                if obj.property('selected') == None:
                    obj.setProperty('selected', True)
                    self.selected = self.files.index(obj)
                else:
                    obj.setProperty('selected', None)
                    self.selected = None
                obj.setStyleSheet('')

        return QObject.event(obj, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

And here is the style.css file:

```
QLabel {
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: none;
}

QLabel[selected=true] {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Unselecting the same file that was selected previously by clicking on it again, seems to be working fine, but other file is not unselected automaticaly when another is selected, why is that and how I can resolve this problem?
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the [`unpolish()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#unpolish) and [`polish()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#polish) method of the widget QStyle:

```py
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress and obj in self.files:
            if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
                if self.selected is None:
                    obj.setProperty("selected", True)
                    self.update_style(obj)
                    self.selected = obj
                elif self.selected is obj:
                    last_state = obj.property("selected")
                    obj.setProperty("selected", None if last_state else True)
                    self.update_style(obj)
                    self.selected = None
                else:
                    self.selected.setProperty("selected", None)
                    obj.setProperty("selected", True)
                    self.update_style(obj)
                    self.update_style(self.selected)
                    self.selected = obj
        return super(MyWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

    @staticmethod
    def update_style(obj):
        obj.style().unpolish(obj)
        obj.style().polish(obj)
```

Comment: I tried it now and it does not seem to be working, previously selected files/dirs remain selected, and unselection by clicking it second time is working just like it previously was.

Comment: @Zarkos mmm I do not understand you. When a QLabel that had no blue color is clicked it changes to blue and if a blue QLabel is pressed then the blue color is removed. Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: yes, in my code above, that part was working, the problem is when I try to select another element, the previously selected element should be unselected automatically, and It did (the property 'selected' was setted to None) but the style did not change, and that is my problem

Comment: @Zarkos Do you want only one QLabel to be selected at a time?

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I want, sorry if I was not able to convey this properly

Comment: @Zarkos Okay, let's say you've pressed the first QLabel for what has been selected, if the second QLabel is pressed then the first QLabel will be deselected and the second QLabel will be selected, what happens if the second QLabel is pressed again?

Comment: if second is pressed again it will be deselected

Comment: yes, now it's working. Can you tell me what was wrong with my code, from a brief view it looks very similar. What I was doing wrong?

Comment: @Zarkos It is not the same logic, besides that your code is confusing. What I can do is explain my logic: The initial "if" verifies the case that there is no label selected so the selected property will have to be changed, in the "elif" I analyze the case that the element pressed is the same so you must change status and the "else" is the case when a new item is selected so the previous item must be deselected.